# Postfix: Port 587 activated by uncommenting a line in master.cf. I see no reference to this at postfix.org. Where is this officially documented?

Tags: postfix

When using Postfix `Port 587` is turned on by uncommenting a line in `master.cf`.

```
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

I found this out by reading posts and comments on various websites.  However I see no reference to this on the official [Postfix Configuration Parameters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) page. That is very frustrating.

Where in the official docs does it say to uncomment the submission parameter in `master.cf`?  I feel like I'm missing out on a lot of important information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is officially documented in [Managing multiple Postfix instances on a single host](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html#why), but although it's very common, it's described as a single case among many possibilities (emphasis is mine):

> **Why multiple Postfix instances**
>
> Postfix is a general-purpose mail system that can be configured to
>   serve a variety of needs. Examples of Postfix applications are:
>
> - Local mail submission for shell users and system processes.
> - Incoming (MX host) email from the Internet.
> - Outbound mail relay for a corporate network.
> - **Authenticated submission for roaming users.**
> - Before/after content-filter mail.
>
> A single Postfix configuration can provide many or all of these
>   services, but a complex interplay of settings may be required, for
>   example with [`master.cf`](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) options overriding [`main.cf`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) settings. In
>   this document we take the view that multiple Postfix instances may be
>   a simpler way to configure a multi-function Postfix system.

The [Postfix Configuration Parameters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) page doesn't tell any of this because it's out of its scope: it just lists the possible parameters you can use in `main.cf`, but doesn't tell how to override them with `master.cf`.

Essentially, "uncommenting the line" and the `-o` (Override  the  named `main.cf` configuration parameter) arguments beneath it is about **starting another instance of a Postfix [component](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#receiving), [`smtpd`](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html)** with different settings:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd

#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

The currently active line is another smtpd instance listening on `smtp` port `25` with the `main.cf` settings, whereas the line beginning with `submission` creates another instance listening on *submission* port `587`. The settings specified with `-o` overrides the settings in `main.cf`, making it possible to add SASL authentication, mandatory encryption etc. that won't be required on normal SMTP between two MTAs (i.e. incoming mail).

In other words, the `service` describes the port and the `command` the Postfix component. You could even have a port number or `ip:port` there, instead:

```
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
# ==========================================================================
587       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
127.0.0.1:10026 inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
```